# Simple script to create link to next joomla menu

Tags: php, html, joomla

What I want is very simple (in theory). I need to create a hyperlink towards the next menu item in joomla.
For example if the page is set on `menu1-->submenu 1--> item 1`, jump to `menu1-->submenu 1--> item 2` . When the items on a submenu are finished, jump to the next submenu and so on.

You can see the page here http://www.vasilatos-construction.com/index.php/en/projects/houses/argostoli-area/argostoli.

From my little knowledge i suspect the solution is php. We need to identify the id of the menu and create a link to id+1. Anyone knows how I can do that?

Comment: So item 1 and item 2 are sub-sub menu links?  Because the menu table is a nested set you can get the entire  tree starting with a given point (there is a method for that) and then using lft (lft+1)  just go through that.

Answer (score 1):

for future reference what i was looking for was this

```
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->id;

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT lft FROM #_menu WHERE id = '$menu'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$lft = $db->loadResult();

$query2 = "SELECT id FROM #_menu WHERE lft = '$lft'+2";
$db->setQuery($query2);
$nid = $db->loadResult();

$query3 = "SELECT id FROM #_menu WHERE lft = '$lft'-2";
$db->setQuery($query3);
$pid = $db->loadResult();

$query4 = "SELECT language FROM #_menu WHERE id = '$menu'";
$db->setQuery($query4);
$lan = $db->loadResult();

if ($lan=="en-GB")
{echo '<a href="index.php?Itemid=';
echo $pid;
echo '">Previous <i  class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a> ' ;
echo '<a href="index.php?Itemid=';
echo $nid;
echo '" class="icon-chevron-right"> Next</a>' ;}
else
{echo '<a href="index.php?Itemid=';
echo $pid;
echo '">Προηγούμενο <i  class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a> ' ;
echo '<a href="index.php?Itemid=';
echo $nid;
echo '" class="icon-chevron-right"> Επόμενο</a>' ;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Javascript. See the code below:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
    var current = $('li.current > a').attr('href');
    var next = null;
    var found = false;

    $('.menu a').each( function ()
    {
        var href = $(this).attr('href')
        if ( found )
        {
            next = href;
            return false;
        }

        found = ( href == current );
    });

    if ( next != null ) // here 'next' is the next url you want, if it does exist
});
```

Note that I'm using jQuery here. Inside the `if ( next != null )` you have the next URL. If the current menu item is the last one, next is null.